# SQL search name starting with a to z, case sensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a SQL to search name starting with a to z case-sensitively?

My current solution:

```
select *
from HR.Employees
where name collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as like '[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%';
```

Any better solution?

Comment: So you want to return only those people who nothing but lower case letters? What about spaces or characters outside these 26?

Comment: @Jingwei what does *starting* means in your question?

Comment: it means the first letter

Comment: @Jingwei so if the 2nd letter is upper case do you want it returned or not?

Comment: Yes, I want it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a case-insensitive LIKE in a case-sensitive database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/209546/5203)

Comment: What about the 35 other latin1 lowercase letters ("ªµºßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the ascii code of the 1st char:

```
select *
from HR.Employees
where ascii(substring(name, 1, 1)) between ascii('a') and ascii('z')
```

you could also use `left(name, 1)` function instead of `substring(name, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that you need the first `COLLATE`, but here's an option that should get you what you need.
The important part is to make your comparison string case sensitive.

```
SELECT *
FROM HR.Employees
WHERE name LIKE '[a-z]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN;
```

Comment: Why in the world would somebody downvote this? This the best way to handle this.

Comment: Probably because they want their solution to be voted as the best. Just guessing.

Comment: Possibly, or they don't understand why you used a binary collation instead of something else because they don't know that it is case sensitive.

Comment: @SeanLange I did not downvote, but re-collating a column is [no better](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/209548/5203) performance wise.

Comment: @GSerg yeah. It seems that if case sensitivity is important than the best solution would be to use the right collation on the column (which of course could be inherited from the table or even the database).

Comment: There's a small advantage on using the collation change instead of multiple functions. The collation option won't prevent parallelism, while using BETWEEN with functions will prevent it.